# How to add animation to margin property of TextBlock in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation, margin

I want to make TextBlock like this

[image: margin change when text changed]

But,

```
aTextBlock.BeginAnimation(Button.MarginProperty, myDoubleAnimation);
```

get this error

> 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation' cannot be used to animate the 'Margin' property of type 'System.Windows.Thickness'.

I have test in Xaml and get same error:

```
<Border CornerRadius="8" Background="Red" Margin="352,173,214,368">
            <TextBlock   x:Name="TestB"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=MTxt,Path=Text,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                      Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="White"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       FontSize="16">

                <TextBlock.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">                       
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation   
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="TestB"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Margin)"
                                    To="2" 
                                    Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"
                                    RepeatBehavior="2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>

                    </EventTrigger>
                </TextBlock.Triggers>

            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
```

What is your idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [ThicknessAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.thicknessanimation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this. `DoubleAnimation` is for properties of `Double` type.

```
<TextBlock.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ThicknessAnimation   
                    Storyboard.TargetName="TestB"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Margin)"
                    To="2" 
                    Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"
                    RepeatBehavior="2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>

    </EventTrigger>
</TextBlock.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks,RoutedEvent for MouseOver Or MouseDown not work, how to set trigger to mouse Event?